# Mocking different passport.js strategies in an integration test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sails.js, integration-testing, passport.js

In the `/config/passport.js` file I've defined and am using different strategies:

```
var
  sails = require('sails'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  CustomStrategy = require('passport-custom').Strategy,
  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
  FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({...}, function(email, password, done){...}));

passport.use('my-custom-strategy', new CustomStrategy(function (req, done){...}));

... same for FB and Google
```

And I want to do an integration test, where I mock the result returned to the controller from these strategies (and focus on the rest of the controller and service processing). Specifically, mocking the `custom-strategy` is important for me.

I could find some scarce examples like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452147/mocking-passport-js-local-strategy-in-a-unit-test) and the [followup link](https://gist.github.com/mweibel/5219403), but could not relate that much to my use cases.

Can anyone give me some code examples that I can start building my tests from?

```
var expect = require('chai').expect
  , request = require('supertest')
  , sinon = require('sinon')
  , passport = require('passport');

describe('/auth', function () {
   it('should return correct authentication response with tokens', function (done) {
      // here I want to mock the custom strategy (or any other)

      var requestBody = {
         // some info
      };

      request(url)
        .post('/auth')
        .send(requestBody)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }

          console.log(res.body);

          done();
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To me from your question it is not clear exactly what functions you want to mock.

I would interpret two problem scenarios here:

Either you want to mock the authentication itself, f.e. to test API controllers relying on an authenticated user. For this scenario the provided links are one possible way. Just write another authentication mechanism which fakes a logged in user. The mock strategy would not go through all the code than a real strategy would but just does the minimum what needs to be done. Maybe also manipulation the database if needed. There is nothing much to be added here if your question is not more specific.

The other scenario is that you want to test the strategy itself. So you want to mock external i/o which your strategy relies on. This can be user input / http traffic and/or database interaction. Since user input usually is collected on the server using http traffic and lots of strategies use external servers to authenticate I would suggest to mock the actual http traffic the way you need it to test your strategy. You can do this using [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock). For the database interactions you could f.e. setup a testing db.